# What kind of service I need to point multiple domains to different webpages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain, hosting, amazon-s3, dns-hosting

I would like to provide my users a way to publish their site, meaning I'll be hosting it and I would provide them the DNS information so they can point their custom domain to it.

I'm totally new on this field so my question might seem a bit weird, so sorry about that in advance.

I'm currently using S3 and I created a bucket with many folders. Each folder being a user's website published in "my hosting" (s3).
I would like each folder to be able to be accessed through a domain, but I was told that's not common and in fact, probably not easy.

I'm open to new suggestions and I'm considering different ways but I'm a bit lost.

Do I need a "Reseller" hosting in order to do this?
I definitely do not want having to maintain / update / monitor my own server and I want it to be scalable, as I don't know in advance how many websites I will have to be hosting and how much data transfer they will require.

In case this helps, all websites will be 100% static.

Comment: This is way off topic here, and the question is so broad it can't be meaningfully answered.

Comment: Is it? I though it is a "server" issue :)
Do you suggest me other place where I can ask such a question? I'm just trying to figure out what kind of server / service I need to provide users with hosting and potential domain for it. But I can't seem to find good answers to this when I google for this so I though I could ask in the experts place :)

Comment: I do not do much on AWS, but I suspect S3 buckets are not what you want. I can think up many ways of deploying this using a web server and/or web proxy. This is a server issue only in as much as S3 uses servers. It would be less off topic on superuser.com but the question is badly defined. How important is S3? How do users publish their sites? How will you maintain the solution? What kind of logging/control/over site? Redundancy and caching requirements? How scalable? Do you need to handle https? This is just fornl starters.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to make a separate s3 bucket for each website. There are a number of guides on how to set that up.

Comment: But I've read there's a limit of 100 buckets for S3 account. That's a very low limit if I'm planning to offer my users a way to publish as many sites as they want. That's the reason I moved away from that idea.

Comment: The only other alternative I could think of was to setup a reverse proxy on machine that the domains point to, which is somewhat complicated. Or as a comment suggested, it's really easy to setup your own web server with multiple static websites.